# Website Contact Form stopped working when I moved mailserver

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, postfix, mx-record

I have a Centos server with ZPanel Installed. This server is used for hosting a website.
Previously, I hosted mail on this server using a "Roundcube" mailbox however, I moved to exchange therefore, I pointed the domain MX records to the exchange sever and everything seemed to work fine.
The website is working on one server and mail is working on another however, I just realized that the website's online contact form is still directing the mail to the "Roundcube" mailbox on the webserver and the mail is not being sent to the Exchange Server.

In Summary, the server was previously like this:

> mail.server.com pointed to SERVER1 www.server.com pointed to SERVER1
>
> NOW: mail.server.com points to SERVER2 www.server.com points to
>   SERVER1

.

> SERVER2 should receive ALL mail however, mail which is sent from
>   SERVER1 (via the web form) goes to the old mailbox on SEVER1 and does
>   not go to the exchange mailbox on SERVER2

What things should I look for to troubleshoot this?

I found a MX record in the Z/Panel which I removed however, the issue is still occurring.

FYI: I am using Postfix.

Answer (score 0):

Your mail server on Server1 is still configured to be "authoritative" for that domain. Remove that configuration, restart the mail server, and it'll likely start working.

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure how to do this. Can you explain a little differently? Thanks. :)

Comment: To be brutally honest, this is a prime reason why we encourage people to **not** use GUI control panels like you are - they allow you to remain blissfully ignorant of how things are actually functioning. Until something like this happens, and then it all falls apart. You're running postfix. Read some of postfix's documentation, look at its configuration files. See if you can sort out what part of the configuration is causing this. After you get this done, then uninstall Zpanel. Seriously. :)